# Cannot run pytest anymore because importlib-metadata entry_points() fails with configparser.DuplicateOptionError

Tags: python, pytest, python-importlib

`pluggy` is used by `pytest`. Recently `pluggy` changed to use `importlib-metadata` instead of `pkg-resources`. Since then I cannot run tests anymore. I launch `pytest` directly from my library (`bliss`) source directory
like I always did, but it now fails at the very beginning with:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/bin/pytest", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 63, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 207, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 289, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 81, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 203, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 94, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 687, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 895, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 836, in _preparse
    self._consider_importhook(args)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 784, in _consider_importhook
    self._mark_plugins_for_rewrite(hook)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 806, in _mark_plugins_for_rewrite
    for name in _iter_rewritable_modules(package_files):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 625, in _iter_rewritable_modules
    for fn in package_files:
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 802, in <genexpr>
    if any(ep.group == "pytest11" for ep in dist.entry_points)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 226, in entry_points
    return EntryPoint._from_text(self.read_text('entry_points.txt'))
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 109, in _from_text
    config.read_string(text)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 722, in read_string
    self.read_file(sfile, source)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 717, in read_file
    self._read(f, source)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1091, in _read
    fpname, lineno)
configparser.DuplicateOptionError: While reading from '<string>' [line 16]: option 'bliss' in section 'console_scripts' already exists
```

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```py
def main():
  ...
  setup(name=meta['name'],
        ...
        entry_points={
            "console_scripts": [
                "bliss = bliss.shell.cli.main:main",
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
   )
```

There is **no duplication** in the `console_scripts` section.

I have no idea why I get this error message...

I narrowed down the problem to `importlib-metadata`, in particular it creates
a `ConfigParser` object to "parse" a entry_points.txt file (which does not
exist ! I don't know where it comes from !), if I pass `strict=False` in the
constructor it makes my tests running again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more information, the `console_scripts` had two entries like this:

```
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "bliss = bliss.shell.cli.main:main",
            ...
            "Bliss = ...",
        ]
```

importlib-metadata has a current bug where it parses this file in a case-insensitive manner

Here's a patch which fixes that: https://gitlab.com/python-devs/importlib_metadata/merge_requests/76